# T-SQL: How to make a positive value turn into the equivalent negative value (e.g "10.00" to "-10.00"

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

Ok so i have a `DECIMAL` field called "Score". (e.g `10.00`)

Now, in my SP, i want to increment/decrement the value of this field in update transactions.

So i might want to do this:

```
SET @NewScore = @CurrentScore + @Points
```

Where `@Points` is the value im going to increment/decrement.

Now lets say `@Points = 10.00`.

In a certain scenario, i want `10.00` to become `-10.00`

So the statement would be translated to:

```
SET @NewScore = @CurrentScore + -10.00
```

How can i do that?

I know its a strange question, but basically i want that statement to be dynamic, in that i dont want to have a different statement for incrementing/decrementing the value.

I just want something like this:

```
SET @Points = 10.00
IF @ActivityBeingPerformedIsFoo
BEGIN
   -- SET @Points to be equivalent negative value, (e.g -10.00)
END
SET @NewScore = @CurrentScore + @Points
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you just multiply it by -1?

Comment: Yep - that's what i was looking for.

Obvious i know, but its too early in the morning to be writing T-SQL without adequate caffeine.

Thanks Chris.

Answer (score 1):

I always do `0 - @Points`.  It was this way in some code I inherited. "A foolish consistency..."

Comment: that would work too.

any difference between between doing it that way and multiplying by -1?

Comment: There is no significant difference between `0 - @Points` and `-1 * @Points` in SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply `@Points` by -1 in that certain scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of subtracting it with a multiple of 2, i.e. `x - 2x`